# SQL remover duplicação mais antiga após a criação da nova

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia,

Tenho um sql que gera uma tabela de PDD e meu problema é o seguinte. Sempre que um título não é pago até o vencimento, ocorre uma renegociação e um novo título é gerado.

Preciso que, quando esse novo título oriundo de uma renegociação for gerado o título original antigo seja removido.

Segue o código e umas imagens do que tenho e do ocorrido.

[Código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoCps.jpg)

[Tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03fx8.jpg)

```
    SELECT 
FIN.NUMCONTRATO, FIN.NUFIN, FIN.NURENEG AS RENEGOCIACAO, FIN.DTVENC, FIN.DHBAIXA, FIN.VLRDESDOB AS VALOR_ORIGINAL, AD_STATUS AS STATUS_CONTRATO
FROM
SANKHYA.TGFFIN FIN 
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TCSCON CON ON (FIN.NUMCONTRATO = CON.NUMCONTRATO) 
WHERE 
FIN.NUMCONTRATO > 0 AND FIN.CODEMP = 1
AND YEAR(FIN.DTVENC) >= YEAR(GETDATE())-1
ORDER BY FIN.NUMCONTRATO, FIN.NUFIN, FIN.DTVENC
```

Conforme visto na imagem da Tabela, os títulos nas linhas 399 e 400 são os originais e os títulos nas linhas 412 e 413 são os gerados após a renegociação. Eles possuem o mesmo código de renegociação.

Preciso pegar esses códigos de Renegociação, filtrar se há outros iguais e em caso positivo deletar o mais antigo baseado na data de vencimento.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda. Desculpe se houver algo fora do padrão para perguntas e se precisarem de mais dados para fornecer uma resposta eu coloco sem problemas.

Answer (score -3):

Eu faria com trigger, no insert do registros já verifica se há uma negociação com o ID mais antigo e exclui.

Ou, faz um procedimento a parte para fazer a limpeza de tempos em tempos.

Complementando. Nesse cenário, o ideal é ter um Job que faça essa limpeza periodicamente. Deixa os comandos em uma procedure e cria o Job para rodá-la. Além de ficar separado as responsabilidades, evita um custo maior de banco durante o INSERT.

Conforme o comentário do Augusto e do Motta, não sei qual o seu ramo de negócio e nem sei se isso entra nesse critério. Mas se atente a exclusão de registros, normalmente não excluímos registros, apenas sinalizamos a exclusão.

Comment: Aconselho a não remover e sim fazer alguma marcaçào para se manter um histórico.

Comment: Isso com certeza

Comment: Eu faria por Procedure , rastreando a operação com opção de "desfaz".

Comment: Estou sinalizando para a avaliação pois possivelmente essa resposta é prejudicial. Não sou especialista em direito porém no Brasil o código civil estipula que dados sobre contratos renegociação para devedores duvidosos devam ser armazenados por até cinco anos. Talvez fosse melhor orientar ao autor da pergunta que consultasse o corpo jurídico da empresa que trabalha solicitando esclarecimento de como proceder na implementação da regra de negócio.

Comment: Compreendo Augusto. Mas dowvote de algo que nem temos certeza? O foco é a questão técnica, correto?

Comment: O autor da pergunta escreveu *"...Tenho um sql que gera uma tabela de PDD..."*. PDD é Provisão para Devedores Duvidosos. Além da questão do tempo de armazenamento da LGPD também tem a questão contábil onde o contrato de PDD renegociado não deve ser removido e sim estornado pois a renegociação deve aparecer no histórico contábil.